# What are the pros and cons of a cheap 3rd-party wireless remote control for Canon 1Ds Mark II?

Tags: canon, remote, canon-1ds-mark-ii

I have a Canon 1Ds Mark II. This means that it has a N3 connector for remote control.

I found something affordable [here](http://www.meritline.com/canon-wireless-remote-controller---p-37222.aspx?source=fghdac) but unfortunatelly they doesn't provide too much informations about the product itself, shipping costs etc.

I would be interested in something similar but I'd like to know more what I'm buying, shipping costs and user experience.

Also, a thing which which concerns me is the significant price difference between the above item and a 'regular' remote controller from B & H (see [here](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/654651-REG/Vivitar_VIV_RC_200_40D_VIV_RC_200_40D_Wireless_Remote_Shutter.html)).

I mention also that I'm **not** interested in *infrared* controllers.

Also, if the product has inside a wired solution, together with the wireless, would be a plus.

Comment: I'll bite... it seems strange to be so concerned about a $30 price difference when you've got a $7k-USD-when-new camera body...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [Hähnel Giga T Pro 2.4GHz Wireless Timer Remote](http://www.hahnel.ie/index.cfm?page=dslrremotecontrols&id=60&pId=60) which can work as simple wireless or wired remote, timer, bulb mode timer, has delays and interval mode (for example for time-lapse photography).

You can use the remote controller (the one with LCD display and buttons) connected with wire to the camera or use the remote controller with wireless receiver connected to the camera.

Maybe not as cheap as others, but not that expensive either, can do great deal of stuff and works like charm. I use it with Canon 1D Mark II.

Answer (score 1):

I can't address the Meritline remote but I use the Phottix Cleon II (http://www.phottix.com/wireless-remotes/phottixr-cleon-ii.html) with my Nikon D300 and I have no complaints.
It's my first non-IR wireless remote so I don't have anything to compare it to.

Phottix make versions for most of the popular cameras. I think the Vivitar unit at B&H is a rebranded Cleon.

The Cleon II includes a wired option but it's not very long.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Pixel TW-282 with my 5D Mark iii and it works pretty well.  The big difference is build quality.  For example, there was a minor problem with the connector on the receiver I got.  I had to loosen one of the screws a bit to get a reliable connection to the remote port on my 5D Mark iii.  Additionally, there is a bit more lag than there would be with Canon's remote from what I understand.

These aren't unmanageable limitations and for the difference in price ($80 vs $300) I'm perfectly content with the limitations, but it is worth noting that there are differences between the generally rugged (and still overpriced) gear that is first party and the cheap knock off stuff that is third party.  In general, I personally probably wouldn't go with a cheap remote for professional work due to reliability concerns, but it works great for when I am using my rig for personal work (which is the only time I needed a remote).